# Graphics Error, Why is the program Crashing?

Tags: c++, c++11, bgi

I am trying to make a bar for each object of the class test. There's a private variable, status. If the value of `status == 0` the bar changes color to red else it changes color to green. After multiple inputs from the for loop, the graphics window of the program crashes. Please assist me where am I doing wrong?

```
/* bar example */ 


#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>

class test
{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        test()
        {


        }   

    int getX()
        {
            if(x==0)
            {
                cout << "Room Empty";
            }
            else
            if (x==1)
            {
                cout << "Room Occupied";
            }
            return x;
        }

    void setX(int check)
        {
            x=check;
            this->update();

        }
    void update()
    {
        //Block to change the colour of the bar on the screen
        if(x==0)
            {
            setfillstyle(INTERLEAVE_FILL,RED);
            bar(100,100,20,20);

            }
            else
            if(x==1)
            {
            setfillstyle(INTERLEAVE_FILL,BLUE);
            bar(100,100,20,20);

            }
    }   

};

int main(void)

{
   /* request autodetection */
   int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, errorcode;
   int midx, midy, i;
   /* initialize graphics and local variables */
   initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "");
   /* read result of initialization */
   errorcode = graphresult();

   if (errorcode != grOk) {   /* an error occurred */

      printf("Graphics error: %s\n", grapherrormsg(errorcode));



      printf("Press any key to halt:");

      getch();

      exit(0);               /* terminate with an error code */

   }
   int x;

   test object;
   for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
   {

   cout << "Enter 0 for red, 1 for Blue: ";

   cin >> x;


   object.setX(x);

   }


      //getch();

         /* clean up */

   closegraph();

   return 0;

   }
```

Comment: Please Help, Im eagerly waiting for it

Comment: Is it possible to reduce this to an MVCE? There are many debuggers for C++. You probably need to get to know one.

Comment: Being a noob, whats MVCE?